# Why does my code produce this output (basic Python)?

Tags: python

This is a program to count the number of times the letter "o" appears in a sentence.

```
sentence = "We hold these truths to be self-evident..."
number_of_Os = 0
for i in sentence:
    if i == "o":
        number_of_Os += 1
print(number_of_Os)
```

This program works, but it only counts lowercase. I want to count BOTH uppercase AND lowercase.

So I changed this line:

if i == "o":

to this:

if i == "o" or "O":

```
sentence = "We hold these truths to be self-evident..."
number_of_Os = 0
for i in sentence:
    if i == "o" or "O":
        number_of_Os += 1
print(number_of_Os)
```

The second program counts EVERY character in the string, not just the o's.

Why does it do this?

Comment: `if i.lower() == 'o':`

Comment: In Python, `”O”` is truthy (it’s not the empty string) so `i == "o" or "O"` is always `True` because it’s parsed as `(i == "o") or "O"`. You want `i in “oO”`, I think.

Comment: i in “oO” works for what I was trying to do, thanks!

Comment: if i.lower() == 'o'   also works!

Comment: I was a little nervous bc this was my first question, so thanks Barmar and Ben for helping!